# Proper holomorphic map and measure of distance away from critical values

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, complex-geometry, several-complex-variables

Let $D_1$ and $D_2$ be two bounded domains in $\mathbb{C}^n$. Let $f:D_1 \to D_2$ be a proper holomorphic map and $V = \{z \in D_1: Det[f'] = 0\}$. Let $U_{\epsilon} = \{z \in D_2: dist(z, f(V)) < \epsilon \}$.  Show that is $m(U_\epsilon) = O(\epsilon^2)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure?

Work so far:
Since $f$ is a proper holomorphic map and $V$ is a variety, $f(V)$ is also a variety.  Thus, $f(V)$ is an analytic set, its codimension is greater than or equal to 1, and its Lebesgue measure is equal to 0.  The fact that its Lebesgue measure equals 0 isn't sufficient, but maybe the codimension requirement is?

I believe my question has now been reduced to if $f(V)$ is a holomorphic variety in a bounded domain and if $U_\epsilon = \{z \in D_2: dist(z, f(V)) < \epsilon\}$, then is $m(U_\epsilon) = O(\epsilon^2)$?

Comment: What is your definition of variety ? I believe that $(x,y) \mapsto (x,xy)$ is proper but the image of $\Bbb C^2$ is not an analytic set, as it is $\Bbb C^2 \backslash \{(v,0) : v \neq 0 \}$.

Comment: $V \subset D_1$ is a holomorphic variety if $V$ is closed in $D_1$ and for every point $p \in D_1$, there is a neighborhood $N(p) \subset D_1$ containing $p$ so that $V \cap N(p) = Z(f_1) \cap \cdots \cap Z(f_r)$ where $f_1, ... , f_r$ are holomorphic in $N(p)$.

Comment: @N.H. Your map is not proper because the preimage of $\{(0, 0)\}$ is $0 \times \mathbb{C}$ which is not compact

Comment: Sure you are right, sorry for my false counter-example.